# how to raise two popup windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I planed to create a popup to my website . keep on searching i find a code to create a popup new window to my website .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.onclick= function(){
window.open('popup creating website', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
}</script>
```

With the above code i the popup new window is creating for every click . It become a big nuisance to vistor .

Keep on searching the result is nill and zero in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) i find but the code is not suted to my website . The code i am trying to get is

> when the page refresh and first click on website should raise popup .

Can any one help me to get out of my problem..!!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to open a popup only on the first click. Just use `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` to get rid of it after the first click.

Here's the working code:

```
function createPopup() {
    window.open('popup creating website', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', createPopup);
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', createPopup);
```

Comment: Thanks.. for your reply..   how can i make to popup windows

Answer (score 0):

To produce a popup,you need to use Javascript,for example:

```html
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert("10/63");
    }

    function a2() {
        alert("13/10");
    }

    function a3() {
        alert("37/30");
    }
    function a4() {
        alert("4/21");
    }
</script>
<p>Click the button.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Example 1 Answer</button>
<br>
<button onclick="a2()">Example 2 Answer</button>
<br>
<button onclick="a3()">Example 3 Answer</button>
<br>
<button onclick="a4()">Example 4 Answer</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to tell if it's the first click:

```
var firstClick = true;
document.body.onclick = function() {
    if (firstClick) {
        window.open('popup creating website', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
        window.open('popup creating second website', 'poppage2', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 200, top = 10');
        firstClick = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. how can i make two popup windows... or any new tab

Comment: Call `window.open` twice.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments i fouded the correct answer what i expected

-

- For single popup --->> New window
  `<script type="text/javascript">
  var firstClick = true;
  document.body.onclick = function() {
  if (firstClick) {
      window.open('popup site', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
      firstClick = false;
  }
  }
  </script>`
- For Two popups -->> new window
  `<script type="text/javascript">
  var firstClick = true;
  document.body.onclick = function() {
  if (firstClick) {
      window.open('popup creating website', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 300, top = 50');
      window.open('popup creating second website', 'poppage2', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 200, top = 10');
      firstClick = false;
  }
  }
  </script>`